# Remove Node Indent from TreeViewNode in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I do have a asp:TreeView control on my Asp.net page and when I render it there comes an empty indent area which pushes the nodes to right hand side which is actually mucking up the design as seen in the image below. So is there any way to remove that indent completely.Because it ruins my page design.

Thanks..

P.s : To show you the problem I used firebug an extension for firefox.

Image : 
[alt text http://www.pixelshack.us/images/sfpp0pa4jjq6t3tbifd.jpg](http://www.pixelshack.us/images/sfpp0pa4jjq6t3tbifd.jpg)

Comment: I think there is no one here who answers this question ? :-(

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay actually at this point JQuery helped me to find a quick solution.

This what I did :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".TreeView tbody tr td:nth-child(1)").hide();
    });
</script>
```

This is the easiest way to solve the problem to me. Thanks JQuery's powerful selectors.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is three years too late, but here is the simplest solution, without a dependency upon either jQuery or CSS 3 as in the previous solutions. The image is referenced in the "NoExpandImageUrl" property which you can just change to a spacer.gif smaller than the leading of the line.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server"
DataSourceID="ds1" 
CssClass="LeftMenu" 
CollapseImageUrl="/images/leftNavBullet0.gif" 
ExpandImageUrl="/images/leftNavBullet.gif"
NoExpandImageUrl="/images/spacer.gif"
>
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

And actually the other way to solve this problem is that :

`.TreeView table tbody tr td:first-child
   {
   display:none;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Css fix.

```
.TreeView tbody tr td img{
    display:none;
}
```

jquery fix waits for page to load and makes menu flash. Css fix is better.